# Replacing null field in generated ArcMap Report?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes, reports

I am creating a report from ArcMap and I would like for the null value fields to be replaced with either a blank or a 0 , but only in the generated report not in the actual attribute field.

Is this possible and, if so, how would you do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can make some computation using the [report designer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Calculating_fields_in_reports/004v0000001w000000/).

> Open a report in the Report Designer.
>
> From the Design Elements list,
> click TextBox and drag the element into position on the report layout.
>
> Enter an expression in the Data Field area in the Element Properties
> grid. Expressions always begin with an equals (=) sign

In you case, the expression should be something like

```
=(condition) ? value_if_true : value_if_false

=(YourField == System.DBNull.Value) ? " " : YourField

=(YourField == System.DBNull.Value) ? 0 : YourField
```

Comment: Perfect, that is it!